# Need explanation of the usage of assembler and Linux signal processing

Tags: c, linux, assembly, operating-system

I was working on an exception handler in C++. It will be used in a messaging protocol for maximum reliability - I want to get an answer back from a process that received a message at all times - even if the process catches a segfault. I know C++ doesn't raise exceptions for null pointer dereferencing, or division by zero, but Java, which is written in C does. That got me thinking and looking around. Eventually I found this little library:

https://code.google.com/p/segvcatch/source/browse/trunk/lib/

My question is in regards to file x86_64-signal.h. I don't completely understand the details of HANDLE_DIVIDE_OVERFLOW. REX byte? What is that? What does RESTORE2 do? What is _Jv_catch_segv and _Jv_catch_fpe? I understand the basic meaning of **catch**, but where are they defined?

Ideally if someone could go through the file top to bottom and address the key points that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this stuff, but I'll answer as best I can.

Starting with the REX byte test:

```
if ((_rip[0] & 0xf0) == 0x40)  /* REX byte present.  */               
  {                                                                   
    unsigned char _rex = _rip[0] & 0x0f;                              
    _is_64_bit = (_rex & 0x08) != 0;                                  
    _rip++;                                                           
  }
```

The REX byte is an instruction prefix used in 64-bit mode. If the high 4 bits of the first byte of an instruction match `0x40`, you know you have a REX prefix byte. And if bit 3 (the W field) is set to 1, that means the operand size is 64 bits. `_rip++` is just skipping the over the prefix.

```
if (_rip[0] == 0xf7)
```

`F7` tells us this is an integer division instruction of some sort.

```
  {                                                                   
    bool _min_value_dividend = false;                                 
    unsigned char _modrm = _rip[1];
```

The next byte is the ModR/M byte which usually gives the details of the operands, but in this case also determines the type of division instruction.

```
    if (((_modrm >> 3) & 7) == 7)
```

The REG field (bits 3 to 5) of the ModR/M byte usually represents a register, but here it's an extension of the instruction's opcode. If it's 7, that means this is a signed division.

```
      {                                                               
        if (_is_64_bit)                                               
          _min_value_dividend =                                       
            _gregs[REG_RAX] == (greg_t)0x8000000000000000UL;          
        else                                                          
          _min_value_dividend =                                       
            (_gregs[REG_RAX] & 0xffffffff) == (greg_t)0x80000000UL;   
      }
```

`0x80000000UL` and `0x8000000000000000UL` are the smallest possible negative numbers in 32 bits and 64 bits respectively. If the eax register (the dividend) matches that value, that means you have the minimum possible dividend.

```
    if (_min_value_dividend)                                          
      {                                                               
        unsigned char _rm = _modrm & 7;                               
        _gregs[REG_RDX] = 0; /* the remainder is zero */
```

If you do have the minimum possible dividend, this set the remainder (edx) to zero, and leaves the dividend in eax as the result.

```
        switch (_modrm >> 6)                                          
          {                                                           
          case 0:  /* register indirect */                            
            if (_rm == 5)   /* 32-bit displacement */                 
              _rip += 4;                                              
            if (_rm == 4)  /* A SIB byte follows the ModR/M byte */   
              _rip += 1;                                              
            break;                                                    
          case 1:  /* register indirect + 8-bit displacement */       
            _rip += 1;                                                
            if (_rm == 4)  /* A SIB byte follows the ModR/M byte */   
              _rip += 1;                                              
            break;                                                    
          case 2:  /* register indirect + 32-bit displacement */      
            _rip += 4;                                                
            if (_rm == 4)  /* A SIB byte follows the ModR/M byte */   
              _rip += 1;                                              
            break;                                                    
          case 3:                                                     
            break;                                                    
          }                                                           
        _rip += 2;                                                    
        _gregs[REG_RIP] = (greg_t)_rip;                               
        return;                                                       
      }
```

The rest of the code is just inspecting the ModR/M byte to determine the number of bytes used by the divisor operand so it can advance the instruction pointer to the next instruction.

Basically this is doing exactly what it says in the commments. If the dividend is the negative integer of largest possible magnitude, the result is equal to the dividend and no exception occurs.

As for `_Jv_catch_segv` and `_Jv_catch_segv`, those are defined in segvpatch.cpp.

```
SIGNAL_HANDLER(catch_segv)
{
    unblock_signal(SIGSEGV);
    MAKE_THROW_FRAME(nullp);
    handle_segv();
}

SIGNAL_HANDLER(catch_fpe)
{
    unblock_signal(SIGFPE);
#ifdef HANDLE_DIVIDE_OVERFLOW
    HANDLE_DIVIDE_OVERFLOW;
#else
    MAKE_THROW_FRAME(arithexception);
#endif
    handle_fpe();
}
```

The `SIGNAL_HANDLER` macro is defined in x86_64-signal.h and expands to something like this:

```
static void _Jv_catch_segv (int, siginfo_t *, void *_p __attribute__ ((__unused__)))
```

Finally, the `RESTORE2` macro, which is essentially called from `RESTORE (restore_rt, __NR_rt_sigreturn)`, expands to:

```
asm                                             
  (                                             
   ".text\n"                                    
   ".byte 0  # Yes, this really is necessary\n" 
   ".align 16\n"                                
   "__restore_rt:\n"                             
   "    movq $__NR_rt_sigreturn, %rax\n"             
   "    syscall\n"                              
   );
```

This creates a sigreturn syscall which is used to return from a signal handler. This is turned into the function `restore_rt` with this line:

```
void restore_rt (void) asm ("__restore_rt")
```

which is set as the restorer function pointer in this code:

```
act.k_sa_restorer = restore_rt;
```

which is used when initialising the two signal handlers in `INIT_SEGV` and `INIT_FPE`.

And I think that about covers all of your questions, but if there is anything that isn't clear or you want me to expand on any particular aspect, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I do have a follow up question:

According to this page "http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html" the sa_restorer is obsolete and should not be used. Do you happen to know what else can be used in its place? Or has that functionality been removed altogether? Or could the main difference be in the type of the struct 'k_sa_sigaction', kernel sigaction that is.

And my last question - is this file based on some basic assembler knowledge, or should I read up a little on advanced OS programming?

Comment: You should be able to figure out the assembly just by reading the [Intel Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). The signal handling is more complicated. I don't do much Unix programming, so this is a bit out of my league, but I would think you need to look at the kernel source to really understand what is going on - it differs from one architecture to the next. It looks safe to drop sa_restorer on some platforms, but on x86-64 for example, it looks like it's still required.